# How to socket_write a 4-byte array in PHP?

Tags: php, sockets

PHP [`socket_write`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-write.php) takes a string and length as parameters. I am not sure how can I convert a 4-byte array (`xmlHeader`) to a string, as some of the bytes are zeroes, i.e.:

```
xmlHeader = unpack("C*", pack("L", 260));
print_r(xmlHeader);
```

gives:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 0
    [4] => 0
)
```

Comment: @JakeGould It's not the BOM. It's the header bytes hinting upcoming message length.

Answer (score 0):

PHP supports binary string:

```
$messageHead = pack("L", 260);
socket_write($socket, $messageHead, strlen($messageHead));
```

For 4-byte array `ar`:

```
$messageHead = pack("CCCC", $ar[1], $ar[2], $ar[3], $ar[4]);
```